# Can I look at files my code makes on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have a discord bot that saves JSON files on the dir he is in so it could work on more than one server without colliding.

I finished my code and I uploaded it to heroku for hosting. The thing is , when I ran the code locally I could see the files that were being created for each server for testing but now I don't know how to reach them.

Is there a way to check all the files I have in heroku without downloading everything down?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and then access your files using:

```
heroku login
heroku run bash -a APPNAME
```

But be aware that Heroku uses an ephemeral filesystem. This means that your local filesystem is only accessible to a single dyno, and once the dyno is stopped, restarted, or moved, all files on the local filesystem are destroyed.

You could use a service like Amazon S3 to store your files in a more permanent way.

Comment: I ran bash on my app but now I have a different problem. How do I access the files from the bash. Do I need to do a specific command? or do I need to know the name of the file to access it(the name of the JSON files work on outside variables so I am not sure what is the name of all of them)?

Comment: I tried to use ls but it doesn't seem like I can see the JSON files on there